# Can't filter on highest newcount in SQL

Tags: sql, nested

I want the badgenumber (MifareID) and corporateID (persnr) from certain people (see filter in the where clause). This specific person has had multiple badges in the past and for every new badge there is a new line with a higher newcount. I only need the latest badge so this is where the newcount is highest. Below code gives me al the badges from this person.

```
SELECT tb_cards.ROMCode as 'MifareID', tb_users.oldextid as 'persnr', tb_cards.NewCount as 'NewCount'
from tb_Cards
right join tb_Users on tb_cards.id_user = tb_users.id_user
where oldextid like 'O1551'
```

[image: Result]

I added a max and group by clause but this does not work. What am i doing wrong? Adding romcode and oldextid to the group by gives me all the values like above.

```
SELECT tb_cards.ROMCode as 'MifareID', tb_users.oldextid as 'persnr', max(tb_cards.NewCount) as 'NewCount'
from tb_Cards
right join tb_Users on tb_cards.id_user = tb_users.id_user
where oldextid like 'O1551'
group by tb_cards.NewCount
```

[image: error]

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, _except_ those who are arguments to aggregate functions.

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns, at least when several tables are involved. Which table does oldextid belong to?

Comment: Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to get than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: Romcode and newcount are both from table 'tb_cards' and oldextid belongs to table 'tb_users'. I qualify them in the code so you should see it?

Comment: Not in the WHERE clause. (Which is of extra interest when doing outer joins.)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Skip the GROUP BY, instead use a window function to find each user's row with the highest newcount:

```
select * from
(
  SELECT tb_cards.ROMCode as 'MifareID', tb_users.oldextid as 'persnr', tb_cards.NewCount as 'NewCount',
         row_number() over (partition by tb_users.id_user order by tb_cards.NewCount desc) rn
  from tb_Cards
  right join tb_Users on tb_cards.id_user = tb_users.id_user
  where oldextid like 'O1551'
) dt
where rn = 1
```